# I am performing the pull using git but i am getting this error. Any one know solution why i am getting this error?

Tags: git, pull

git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnJxK.png)

Comment: Gosh, call me wild and crazy but I think the problem might be that you have no remote repository at the URL you provided, or that you lack authorization for that repository.

Comment: Also, no pictures of code please. Everything in that screen shot is just text. Copy, paste, and format as text directly in your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Permission+denied+publickey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your remote git URL is correct.
You need to setup the authentication (ssh keys) in your github account, so that your laptop/pc can be trusted by github and you can make a password-less authentication while doing push /pull.

See the doc here

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent